# How to replace (”); }); character

Tags: mysql, replace

When I run the following query, it doesn't work.

```
UPDATE wp_posts
    SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, '(”); });','text here');
```

Comment: How many records are there in wp_posts? (maybe you should use LIMIT)

Comment: 6217 records wp_posts

Comment: I may be wrong but I believe I read somewhere that there is an mysql option to prevent dangerous operation (Delete *, update *...) if no LIMIT or WHERE clause are specified, you can confirm this by adding LIMIT 500 and see how it goes...

Comment: "it doesn't work" What does that mean for you? What happened versus what you want to happen? What has your investigation revealed so far? Programming requires some of your own effort...!

Answer (score 1):

This does work correctly, may be you are using incorrect number of spaces.

```
mysql> select  REPLACE ( 'this is (”); });' , '(”); });','SPARTAAA!!!!');
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| REPLACE ( 'this is (”); });' , '(”); });','SPARTAAA!!!!')     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| this is SPARTAAA!!!!                                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In wordpress,it might be a case that the strings are stored as html entity (eg `&quot; &lt;`) instead of actual character,hence you are not able to replace it.

I would suggest you to use this plugin : http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but i have phpmyadmin access.

Comment: @Fukran, it may be that the strings are html entities, hence not exactly what they appear in HTML.

Comment: No, only text not html tags (”); });

Comment: @FurkanGüzeş, the HTML entities can be quotations marks, apostrophes,etc. eg in your text the closing quote could be stored as `” -> &rdquo; &#8221; &#x201D;`

Answer (score 0):

Did you really mean the "smart quote" `”`, and not the quotation mark `"`?
Are those really what's in your database?

---

<sup>[This *answer* was brought to you today in the form of a rhetorical question.]</sup>

Comment: Search phpmyadmin  (”); });
and 6217 results.


SELECT *  FROM `wpdn_wp`.`wp_posts` WHERE (CONVERT(`post_content` USING utf8) LIKE '%(”);%')  OR  (CONVERT(`post_content` USING utf8) LIKE '%});%') run (”); }); have content.
but i am don't replace (”); }); 
Note: Sorry my English is not perfect.

Comment: Try removing the space after `REPLACE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for these characters and replacing it one by one then you can use:
   replace(replace(replace('tes;(', '(', ''), ')', ''), ';', '').
   So if any of the three characters found; it will replace it.

And if you are looking for whole search as string then what you are doing is working fine.